# Issue in Standard Output and Error

Tags: shell

If I type

```
cat > file.txt 2>&1
```

then `file.txt` is created with the content of `cat`'s standard input. 
But if I do

```
cat > file.txt 1>&2
```

then `file.txt` is created, but the file is empty.

What is the issue between above two commands?

Answer (score 13):

Order is important.  The shell processes file redirections *in the order that it sees them.*  Consider:

```
cat >file.txt 2>&1
```

First, stdout is redirected to the file `file.txt`.  Next, stderr is redirected to stdout which is `file.txt`.  Thus both stdout and stderr are sent to `file.txt`.

By contrast, consider:

```
cat >file.txt 1>&2
```

First, stdout is redirected to the file `file.txt`.  (In doing this, `file.txt` is created as an empty file.)  Next, stdout is redirected to stderr.  Thus, stdout goes to stderr and nothing goes to `file.txt` and, therefore, `file.txt` remains as an empty file.

#### Another Interesting Case

Consider:

```
cat 2>&1 >file.txt
```

First, stderr is redirected to stdout which is still the terminal.  Next, stdout is redirected to `file.txt`.  This second redirection does not affect stderr.  It is still sent to the terminal.  It is **not** sent to `file.txt`.

#### Documentation

This behavior is documented in `man bash`:

> Redirections are  processed
>          in the order they appear, from left to right.

An exception to this order, which is also documented in `man bash`, is pipelines.  Consider:

```
command1 ... | command2
```

The standard output of `command1` is sent by the pipe to the standard input of `command2` and this  connection  is  performed
*before* any redirections specified by the first command.

#### An Example With Pipelines

Consider:

```
command1 >file.txt | command2
```

Because the redirection to `file.txt` occurs *after* the redirection to the pipeline, the stdout of `command1` will go to `file.txt`.  `command2` will receive no input.

Answer (score 2):

Doing '> file' is really doing '1> file'. So what you are doing is redirecting file descriptor 1 twice. Only the last one takes effect.